# Android Dagger 2 not generating component in java/kotlin project

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-2

I really need your help as I can't proceed with my project. The issue I am having is when I try to generate dagger component it seems not available. I use java classes for Dagger component/module and Kotlin classes for the rest of application. I tried it with java only classes and it also doesnt work.

Gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 26
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.gebruiker.beertime1"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
   "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
     }
    buildTypes {
       release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}



     }

   dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.14'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.14'


implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.14'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.14'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.14'

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.9'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
 }
```

My  repository component :

```
package com.example.gebruiker.beertime1.di;

 import com.example.gebruiker.beertime1.MainScreen.MainActivity;

  import javax.inject.Singleton;

  import dagger.Component;

  @Component(modules = NetworkModule.class)
  public interface RepositoryComponent {
   void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
 }
```

My mainactivity component :

```
@Component(dependencies = RepositoryComponent.class ,modules = 
{AppModule.class,RepositoryModule.class,NetworkModule.class})
 interface MainActivityComponent{

void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);

 }
```

Comment: no error when building project?

Comment: no :S do you think the issue may be that I am using java class for dagger classes like components and modules and the rest is in kotlin ? :> I think it should not matter

Comment: Couldn't you go just for kotlin with all project?

Comment: Have you tried `kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.14'`?

Answer (score 4):

You're using `annotationProcessor` instead of `kapt` for some of your dependencies. Change your `build.gradle` to the following and it should work:

```
def final dagger_version = '2.14.1'

implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:${dagger_version}"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:${dagger_version}"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:${dagger_version}"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${dagger_version}"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:${dagger_version}"
```

Comment: I have always used only "dagger-android-support, dagger-compiler & dagger-android-processor" in my projects, have never faced any need for adding other libraries you added. Can you tell me why add those specifically?
BTW kapt works, they should add that to official GitHub readme file, wasted hours on this.